# Recuperar literal de un modelo relacionado en VIEW y JS

Tags: python-3.x, html5, django, datatables

Estoy mostrando un diccionario de listas vía js en un datatable pero no soy capaz de recuperar el literal correspondiente a la FK del modelo.

He intentado filtrar el modelo por id pero al ser un Autofield no permite 'lookup'.

Modelos implicados:

```
class Entities(models.Model): 
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name='Código', max_length=10, blank=False, unique=True,
                                   help_text='Codigo de entidad.')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Nombre', unique=True,
                                   help_text='Nombre de la entidad.')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Descripción',
                                   help_text='Descripción de la entidad.')    
    name_report = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre Reporte', max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True,
                                   help_text='Rellenar para ACTIVAR el reporte')
    long_desc = models.CharField(verbose_name='Descripción Larga', max_length=800, blank=True,
                                   help_text='Descripción larga. Máximo 800 caracteres.')
    language = models.CharField(verbose_name='Idioma', max_length=2, choices=languages, default='ES',
                                   help_text='Idioma del reporte')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=0, verbose_name='Usuario', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                   help_text='Usuario')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Creado',  blank=False, unique=False,
                                   help_text='Fecha de Creación')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Actualizado',  blank=False, unique=False,
                                   help_text='Fecha de Actualización')

    historical = HistoricalRecords()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        return item

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Entidad'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Entidades'
        ordering = ['code', 'name']


class Projects(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entities, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    types = models.CharField(verbose_name='Tipo', max_length=3, choices=types, blank=False, unique=True, default='TRF',
                                   help_text='BAU / TRF')
    code = models.CharField(verbose_name='Código', max_length=10, blank=False, unique=True,
                                   help_text='Codigo Interno del Proyecto')
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre', max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True,
                                   help_text='Nombre del Proyecto')
    phase = models.CharField(verbose_name='Fase', max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True, default="General",
                                   help_text='Fase del Proyecto')
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Descripción',
                                   help_text='Descripción del Proyecto')   
    long_desc = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Descripción Larga',
                                   help_text='Descripción Larga del Proyecto')   
    hours = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Horas', blank=True, unique=False, default=0,
                                   help_text='Horas Presupuestadas')
    start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Fecha Inicio', blank=False, unique=False,
                                   help_text='Fecha Inicio')
    end_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Fecha Final', blank=False, unique=False,
                                   help_text='Fecha Final')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=0, verbose_name='Usuario', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                   help_text='Usuario')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Creado',  blank=False, unique=False,
                                   help_text='Creado')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Actualizado',  blank=False, unique=False,
                                   help_text='Actualizado')

    historical = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}' + '-' + f'{self.phase}'

    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        return item

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Proyecto'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Proyectos'
        unique_together = [['entity', 'types', 'code', 'name', 'phase']]
        ordering = ['entity', 'types', 'code', 'name', 'phase']
```

el JS para mostrar los proyectos:

```
$(function () {
    $('#data').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        destroy: true,
        deferRender: true,
        ajax: {
            url: window.location.pathname,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'action': 'searchdata'
            },
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        columns: [
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "entity"},
            {"data": "types"},
            {"data": "code"},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "hours"},
            {"data": "options"},
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [-1],
                class: 'text-center',
                orderable: false,
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    var buttons = '<a href="/erp/projects/update/' + row.id + '/" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a> ';
                    buttons += '<a href="/erp/projects/delete/' + row.id + '/" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-flat"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>';
                    return buttons;
                }
            },
        ],
        initComplete: function (settings, json) {

        }
    });
});
```

y finalmente la view de proyecto que se ejecuta:

```
class projectsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ValidatePermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Projects
    template_name = 'Projects/list.html'
    permission_required = 'view_Projects'

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = {}
        try:
            action = request.POST['action']
            if action == 'searchdata':
                data = []
                logger.info(data)
                position = 1
                for i in Projects.objects.all():
                    item = i.toJSON() 
                    item['position'] = position
                    data.append(item)
                    position += 1
            else:
                data['error'] = 'Ha ocurrido un error'
        except Exception as e:
            data['error'] = str(e)
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Proyecto'
        context['entity'] = 'Proyectos'
        context['create_url'] = reverse_lazy('erp:projects_create')
        context['list_url'] = reverse_lazy('erp:projects_list')
        return context
```

Necesitaría sustituir el ID 1 de la columna Entidad por el Nombre de la Entidad:
[image: html]

ya no se que mas probar y por donde tirar. no se si el hecho de usar js lo complica mas o no sé. ya ando perdido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCION:**

Sobre el modelo original, modificamos el método toJSON de la siguiente manera:

```
    def toJSON(self):
        item = model_to_dict(self)
        item['entity'] = self.entity.toJSON()
        return item
```

Una vez hecho esto, sobre el JS, sobre la columna afectada la modificamos de la siguiente manera:

```
columns: [
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "entity.name"},
            {"data": "types"},
            {"data": "code"},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "hours"},
            {"data": "options"},
```

Resultado con literal recuperado:

[image: Resultado]